# Large data passing to JSP page from Struts 1.3 Action subclass

Tags: jsp, struts, action

I want to send a large amount of data to a JSP page from an Action subclass.

My questions:

1. What is the most effective way to send data from an Action subclass to a JSP page in Struts?
2. What problems can I face doing so?
3. What if I put two big `ArrayList`s on a request using `request.setAttribute()` and read that request on the JSP page  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are returning large amount of data from action to JSP in Struts 1/2, you are not sending it over the wire. It is not redirecting, but forwarding. This means that the data returned from the action will be available by reference in the JSP. No copying and network transport is involved. Of course if you render a huge content using JSP and the model you've provided, it will take a lot of time to send it back to the client. But communication between the action and the view (JSP) *per se* happens in-memory during the processing of one request. Nothing to be worried about.

I think this applies to every framework that returns model from the controller to the view - nothing is copied, just reference passing. Also using `request.setAttribute` does not copy anything, no cloning is involved.

**Warning**: this does not apply to session attributes, that are persistent across requests, might be serialized and replicated, etc. But request attributes are fine with big objects, as long as you really need them (?)

Comment: Really thanks for the clarification. One More thing i want to know is how to design a model in Struts ? The Application i'm developing stroes a lot of data for various users and planning from the View end is difficult so i want to start planning by creating the model first. What's the best approach to do so ?

Comment: First of all, you should keep in mind that using large model objects all the time will have huge impact on memory consumption under load. You shouldn't hold too much in memory, just enough to serve one particular request. Also use pagination and caching wisely. As far as I remember, `ActionForm` is Struts 1' incarnation of model, there is no other approach.